# How do I edit/replace my password verification program? (Wie verändere(/ersetze) ich mein Passwort-Erkennungsprogramm?)

Tags: password, directory, programming, source-code

(I am able to understand both english and german, but german is my first language, so if you can, pls answer me in german (and please don't roast me for my bad english) :) )
(Ich kann sowohl Deutsch, als auch Englisch verstehen, aber Deutsch ist meine Muttersprache, deshalb wäre es nett, wenn ihr mir wenn möglich auf deutsch antworten würdet :) )

Hello!

Recently I wanted to program something for my laptop (I use Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS) so that I wouldn't have to type in a password (e.g. 1234 or asdf) (to get root authorization or to sign in) but instead it would also recognize the password if it was "shifted" (so it would be e.g. 2345 or 3456 or sdfg or something).
It's not important what I want to program, I just need to know which file(s) I have to replace/modify to reach my goal.
In the laptop files, directory `/`, I sesarched for **pass**. But I found neither the right files nor folders. (I opened them but nothing looked like something that would make sense to me in that case.)
I don't know what else I could do or which files I should investigate, so...:
Where do I find the source code I need to replace/modify to reach my goal?

Thank you very much in advance for your effort. :)
If you need any more information or have any questions in order to understand my problem feel free to message me. :)

---

Hallo!

Ich wollte letztens für meinen Laptop (ich nutze Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS) etwas programmieren, sodass man nicht genau ein Passwort eingeben muss (um root-Berechtigung zu erteilen, oder sich anzumelden), sondern z.B. anstatt "1234" auch "2345" oder "3456" erkannt wird, also auch eine "verschobene" Version des Passworts.
NICHT wichtig ist, WAS ich programmieren möchte, sondern WELCHE Dateien ich ersetzen/modifizieren muss, um mein Ziel zu erreichen.
Ich habe in den "Dateien" in dem Verzeichnis `/` nach **pass** gesucht, aber ich habe weder Dateien noch Ordner gefunden, bei denen ich dachte, dass sie die richtigen sind. (Ich habe sie geöffnet und habe nichts gefunden, was nach meiner Kenntnis an der Stelle sinnvoll zur Lösung des Problems wäre.)
Ich bin also ziemlich ratlos, deshalb:
Wo finde ich den Quelltext, welchen ich ersetzen/bearbeiten muss, um mein Ziel zu erreichen?

Vielen Dank schon mal im Voraus für eure Mühe :)
Falls ihr noch irgendwelche Fragen habt oder weitere Informationen benötigt um das Problem zu verstehen und mir helfen zu können, schreibt mich gern an. :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering in English since that's the main language of this site. While it's unclear to me *why* you would want to be doing this, here are some tips:

The information and passwords of the user accounts of a Linux system are stored in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`. They are stored in hashed form, so you'll need to take that into account if you want to replace something. Please keep in mind that if you write the wrong information into these files, you might not be able to login to your machine any longer.

Authentication is handled by the PAM subsystem. If you are proficient in C, you could write a custom module that would handle shifted passwords like you are asking. Take a look at the documentation here: http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_MWG.html